# How can I avoid repeating code with inline functions?

Tags: c++, inline-method

I have repeating code in my work, and I want to get rid of it, so I know that in C++ it is not good idea to use macro, but instead I must use inline function, is it good idea to use this function as inline:

```
list<Data>::iterator foo(int data){
if(dataExists(data)){
    list<Data>::iterator i;
    for(i = dataClass.begin(); i != dataClass.end(); ++i){
       if(i->getData() == data){
        break;
       }
return i;   //here I have one more problem, what can I return if data doesn't exist?
}
```

I think that this function is very unsafe. How can I improve my code?

Comment: What actually want macro type functionality in C# or code improvement!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing here is already done by the `std::find()` function, so it would be better to use that (although it's certainly OK to try implementing these things yourself for the exercise).

`std::find()` also demonstrates a good way to indicate the "not found" condition -- if the item is not found, it returns the iterator one-past-the-end.  That way, the caller can determine whether a matching item was found by comparing the iterator returned with `Data.end()`.

Comment: Nope, there is not `std::list<T>::find()`.  But there is `std::find()` that you use like this: `std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), dataToFind)`.  See http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/find

Comment: One more thing: You'll have to `#include <algorithm>` to use `std::find()` and friends.

Comment: +1, but in this particular case you will need to use `find_if` together with a predicate that tests the equality of the value returned by the member function and the value you are looking for...

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted makes no sense. at one point you use `Data` as a type, and at another as an object. Assuming it is an object, the way to indicate that something is not found would be to return an iterator pointing to its end.

```
return Data.end();
```

but your code is too confused for this to work without major changes.

You are not going to learn C++ by posting questions on SO - it simply cannot be done. Instead, you need to read a good C++ text book - I recommend [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/), which covers things like iterators in detail. If you carry on askking questions like this, you are simply wasting your time and, more importantly, ours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you are asking here, but there are several misconceptions in your post.

First inline functions are a specific optimization you do not need to care about quite yet. Learn about normal functions first and understand them properly.

As another answer already said, `std::find()` does what you seem to want to do. It doesn't have to be a member of list to work, in fact modern C++ styleguides often prefer non member functions.

Now to your code. I am pretty sure that the code you posted is not working C++ code, which makes it really hard to understand what you are trying to do. The list type you are using is also not a `std::list<>` (The iterators work differently), and you use `Data` as both a variable (which is not defined in your code) and as a type.

As someone already suggested maybe you should start a little easier, or better yet, get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (I recommend "Accelerated C++" and "Programming P&P using C++") for C++ beginners.